# how to add dynamic dictionary in jinja template?

Tags: json, jinja2

I have the below jinja template and i want to achieve the following:

jinja template for json:

```
{
  "spark_conf": {
  {% if cluster_mode == "single" %}
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "singleNode",
        "spark.master": "local[*]",
  {% endif %}
  {% if cluster_mode == "concurrent" %}
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile":"serverless",
        "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages":"sql,python,r",
  {% endif %}
  {{ spark_conf }}
  },
  "spark_env_vars": {{ spark_env_vars }}}
```

I am passing spark_env_vars as parameter and want to add more spark_conf dynamically, so the input to this j2 template is:

```
spark_env_vars = {
    "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
}
spark_conf = {"test": "abc", "test124": "def"}
cluster_mode = "single"
```

Post jinja i am expecting output as :

```
{ "spark_conf" : {
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "singleNode",
        "spark.master": "local[*]",
        "test": "abc",
        "test123": "def"},
  "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    }
}
```

please could you advise how to handle that in jinja template to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [for loop](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for) for dynamic variables:

```
{
    "spark_conf": {
    {%- if cluster_mode == "single" %}
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "singleNode",
        "spark.master": "local[*]",
    {%- endif %}
    {%- if cluster_mode == "concurrent" %}
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile":"serverless",
        "spark.databricks.repl.allowedLanguages":"sql,python,r",
    {%- endif %}
    {%- for key,value in spark_conf.items() %}
        "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
    },
    "spark_env_vars": {
    {%- for key,value in spark_env_vars.items() %}
        "{{ key }}": "{{ value }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
    "spark_conf": {
        "spark.databricks.cluster.profile": "singleNode",
        "spark.master": "local[*]",
        "test": "abc",
        "test124": "def"
    },
    "spark_env_vars": {
        "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
    }
}
```

With `loop.last` special variable we can check whether the current element is the last one, and skip putting a comma at the end.